# iOS download resources when building application

Tags: ios, xcode

Is it possible to download some resources when building the application to the device? I don't want to do this when first running it because internet may not be available then. Instead I would like to download these resources when the application itself is being downloaded from the appstore or right after it finished downloading.

Comment: Why don't you add these resources to your app before submitting it to the app store?

Comment: @NikosM He could be worried about creating an App that exceeds the App store download size limit.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. The only time your application can do anything is while it is running, so you will have to wait for the first run. As NikosM asked, why not just put the information in your app bundle?

Answer (score 2):

Many applications rely on some database of additional information that they do not download until the application runs for the first time. Why not just do that - have your application itself download the information when it runs, and place it where it can get at it from then on? This is a very common strategy.